# UICollectionView 3 column grid, 1px space?? (image included)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have setup a UICollectionView with a FlowLayout that leaves no space in between cells in either the vertical or horizontal directions.

I have everything working, yet there is an odd 1px space between the 2nd and 3rd column and I have no idea why!? I have verified the 1px gap shows up both in iOS simulator and on a real device. Has anybody experienced this?

My UIViewController is a delegate/datasource of the following:

`class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

I have implemented the necessary functions to remove any spacing (and verified with print statements that they are running), as well as visual confirmation of the cells lining up next to each other:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Finally, I have printed out the width of the cell being returned (each color square) to verify it was the `(view.frame.width / 3)` or `(320/3)`, which is 106.666667

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var totalHeight: CGFloat = (self.view.frame.width / 3)
    var totalWidth: CGFloat = (self.view.frame.width / 3)

    println(totalWidth) // this prints 106.666666667

    return CGSizeMake(totalWidth, totalHeight)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a better solution than those below to solve this?

Comment: @BlueBoy I have not. The solution I go with is to make two of the columns a ceil or floor of (width/3), and then set the third column to the remainder.

Comment: How do you make just two of the columns a ceil?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better avoid number's double type in similar situations.
Use:

```
return CGSizeMake(ceil(totalWidth), ceil(totalHeight))
```

Comment: But don't I want the size (width and height) of the cells to be floats? When I implement this code, only 2 cells show up per row, since 107+107+107 = 321, which is > the view width of 320.

Comment: at least, you can make 107+107+(320-214)

Comment: You are right - that works...but why would this matter since CGSizeMake takes CGFloats as input parameters?

Comment: it takes long numbers for any cases, and how to use number in specific cases is your choice.

Comment: but if I want itemSpace = 1 px  , I tired, the first space is 1 px, but the second space is always 2 px ， the itemspace isn't equal  but I want them to be equal

Comment: @rose, you need to determine logic of rendering in UICollectionView.
Don't forget it's adaptive.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, I fixed it with the code below:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * 4
    let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingspace
    let widthPerItem  = availableWidth/3

    return CGSizeMake(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
}
```

and define the variable below in the begin of your class:

```
fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.5, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

For example you have screen width = 320, when you divide it by 3 you have 106.6666. If consider it as Int, we have: 106 * 3 = 318. We need 2 pixel to be added by 1 px to first two cells because 320 - 318 = 2. Try this solution below.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let columns = 3 
    let width = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    let side = width / columns
    let rem = width % columns
    let addOne = indexPath.row % columns < rem
    let ceilWidth = addOne ? side + 1 : side
    return CGSize(width: ceilWidth, height: side)
}
```

Comment: I'd been trying for hours to solve a similar issue and this is the only solution that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to issue just make middle cell of width 106 and other two with width 107 in method collectionView layout

```
NSInteger numColumns = 3;
CGSize deviceSize;
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width / numColumns;
CGFloat height = width ;
NSInteger rem = (int)self.view.frame.size.width%numColumns; 
if(indexPath.row == (1 + numColumns*counter) && rem != 0) {  

    deviceSize = CGSizeMake(floor (width), ceil(height));
    counter++;
}
else {

    deviceSize = CGSizeMake(ceil (width), ceil(height));
}
deviceSize = CGSizeMake(deviceSize.width, deviceSize.height);
```