# still got space when I set minSpace to 0 CollectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I now have a collectionView with 4 cells per row.

I've set layout like the following

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4

let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        self.module_CollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

which should give me a collectionView without any spacing between cells.

However, I still got very thin (looks like 1px) space between columns.

(please refer to the screen shot below)

It works fine if the cell width is 1/5 or 1/3 of Screen width.

I guess it's because the remainder or something ?

Would be good if someone could point out what might goes wrong.

thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might set wrong constraint, otherwise nothing is wrong in your code for flowlayout.

Now, first take one `UIView` in your `collectionviewcell` and set it's four constraint - `top.leading,trailing,bottom` with constant `0`.

Then add your all the stuff (your views or images or buttons) in that view and give proper constraint.

Comment: thanks for replying, 
But the only constraint I use if to center the imageView and the Label in Xib 
I don't see how constraint will have a impact on spacing :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441547/uicollectionview-3-column-grid-1px-space-image-included

I think it's more like the following issue.

Comment: are you adding imageview and label directly in cell ? or have you taken view as container view ?

Comment: If you are adding directly then it may be occur! You should take one view first with four constraint as i mentioned in answer and then add your imageview and label in that view and you will not find any space then!

Comment: I did add them directly, I will give it a try now and let you know asap

Comment: make sure that your cell and uivew both have same size and you have set four constraint `top,bottom,leading and trailing`!

Comment: I did, 100% sure

Comment: and if you are testing in simulator then make sure that it have full scale (with simulator open press : cmd + 1)

Comment: I've tested in simulator and my device, same result . :'(

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`.

In your case, the screen width is `375`, and you want to divides it to `4` parts. If you directly divides `375` to `4` parts, you'll get `93.75`, with decimal.
You should round it(decimal) to an integer like `94 + 94 + 94 + 93 = 375` instead of `93.75+93.75+93.75+93.75 = 375`.

For Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let screenWidth:Int = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let parts:CGFloat = 4
        var rounding:Int = 0

        if(screenWidth.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: parts) != 0) {
        rounding = Int(screenWidth.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: parts))
        }
}
//----
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var roundingWidth = 0
        if(rounding != 0) {
        rounding -= 1
        roundingWidth = 1
        }

        return CGSize(width: Int(screenWidth / parts) + roundingWidth, height: yourHeight)
}
```