# UICollectionView BackgroundView Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to add a custom, interactive view behind a `UICollectionView` (represented by the yellow background in the picture). The easiest way I've found to do this is by using the `backgroundView` property on my `UICollectionView`. The only issue is that if a I add spacing between the cells, the background view is visible between the spaces. To combat this, I've made the cell spacing 0, and have mimicked black grid lines by adding a margin around the `UIImageView`s in the cells (represented by the purple squares) and then making the background of the cells black. This works perfectly for the horizontal spacing above and below the cells, but for some reason the background view is still visible through a narrow vertical line between them. I have made sure that the cell widths are exactly half that of the `UICollectionView`, and that the `minimumLineSpacing` and `minimumInteritemSpacing` are both 0.0.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried these both - cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black, cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

Comment: @VincentJoy Yes; it doesn't change the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested I discovered a solution in this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561816/5225013

This is the code I used from @Asike, slightly modified to fit my use case. It increases the cell widths if their combined calculated widths don't perfectly equal the total width of the collectionView. This occurs on some screen sizes/scales due to decimal places.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let columns = 2
    let width = Int(collectionView.bounds.width)
    let side = width / columns
    let rem = width % columns
    let addOne = indexPath.row % columns < rem
    let ceilWidth = addOne ? side + 1 : side
    return CGSize(width: ceilWidth, height: side)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created the same scenario as yours. And it is working fine for me with the below code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let backView = UIView(frame: self.collectionView.bounds)
        backView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
        self.collectionView.backgroundView = backView
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 2, height: collectionView.bounds.width / 2)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
    }
}
```

The only thing, I've used cell's `borderWidth` for illustration. You can change that as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: I created a fresh project and tested your code, and it doesn't fix the issue. This mainly happens on iPhone X, if that helps.

Comment: Have you used the exactly same code? Because its working fine at my end.

Comment: Yeah, I used exactly the same code. I figured out what the issue is in another thread though and posted it in the answer. Cheers!